# Accessing an action class properties in another Action class in struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm a newbie to struts.
I have gone through most of the StackOverflow articles which relates my situation. But it doesn't help me a lot.

Below is one among them.

[How to pass Action class variable value into another Action class in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087199/how-to-pass-action-class-variable-value-into-another-action-class-in-struts-2)

**Scenario:**

I have to display a comparison view which contains three Iframes in it. Each Iframe will invoke(embeds) other JSP page or other action.

I'm preparing my dataset in an Action class where I need to pass it to First jsp(Comparison view jsp).

From Comparison view jsp, either I need to pass the value to **other jsp** or 
to other **Action class**.

Comment: It depends how you're doing this. In general, if you're (essentially) opening a URL, you don't pass anything other than strings, just like any URL opening.

Comment: I don't want to pass that particular value along with url. For my scenario, currently, I'm writing a separate action class(2nd action) where I'm preparing data in the second action which is not appropriate.